# PayPal購入画面について

Tags: php, paypal

SetExpressCheckoutにて商品名、購入金額等を渡していますが、PayPal購入画面に商品名、購入金額等が表示されなくて困ってます。
指定方法は以下のようになっています。
何か指定方法に不備があるか、わかる方ご解答お待ちしております。

```
$ec_request =& PayPal::getType('SetExpressCheckoutRequestType');
$ec_request->setVersion("51.0");

// Set request-specific fields.
$paymentAmount = ($aPurchaseCommodityInfo->unit_price * $aPurchaseCommodityInfo->amount) + $aPurchaseCommodityInfo->postage;
$currencyID = 'USD'; // or other currency code ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')
$paymentType = 'Sale'; // or 'Order' or 'Authorization'

$ec_details =& PayPal::getType('SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType');
$ec_details->setReturnURL($aReturnUrl);
$ec_details->setCancelURL($aCancelUrl);
$ec_details->setPaymentAction($paymentType);
$ec_details->setNoShipping('1', 'iso-8859-1'); //PayPal画面に配送先住所未表示

$amt_type =& PayPal::getType('BasicAmountType');
$amt_type->setattr('currencyID', $currencyID);
$amt_type->setval($paymentAmount, 'iso-8859-1'); //購入金額
$paymentDetailsItem = &PayPal::getType('PaymentDetailsItemType');
$paymentDetailsItem->setName($aPurchaseCommodityInfo->commodityName); //商品名
$paymentDetailsItem->setQuantity('1', 'iso-8859-1'); //購入数
$paymentDetailsItem->setAmount($paymentAmount, 'iso-8859-1'); //購入金額
$ec_details->setOrderTotal($amt_type); //購入金額合計

$ec_request->setSetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails($ec_details);

$caller =& PayPal::getCallerServices($this->profile);

// Execute SOAP request.
$response = $caller->SetExpressCheckout($ec_request);
```

Comment: 言語名をタグに入れていただけるとわかりやすく、他の方が検索する際にも役立つかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コーディングを見る限りですが、`$paymentDetailsItem`が`$ec_details`に関連付けられていませんので、結果として`$paymentDetailsItem`での設定内容はAPIで送信されていません。

```
$paymentDetails = &PayPal::getType('PaymentDetailsType');
$paymentDetails->setPaymentDetailsItem($paymentDetailsItem);
$ec_details->setPaymentDetails($paymentDetails);
```

のようなコーディングで、`$paymentDetailsItem`を`$paymentDetails`に関連付け、
`$paymentDetails`を`$ec_details`に関連付けることで`$paymentDetailsItem`での設定がAPIで送信されるようになります。

なお、`$ec_request->setVersion(""51.0"");`のままですと`$paymentDetailsItem`での指定がAPIで送信されてもPayPalの決済画面に表示されませんので、これを機会に最新番号の`$ec_request->setVersion(""123.0"");`とすることをお薦めいたします。

Comment: [バージョン履歴](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/release-notes/#MerchantAPI)を見ると現在の最新バージョンは122のようですが、123を指定してもいいのですか？また51と123はだいぶ離れていますが、気軽に変更してもいいのでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、タイプミスでした。122ですね。
新しいバージョンに変更しても問題ないと思います。新しいバージョンでは新機能が使えるようになりますが、既存機能はそのまま動作すると思います。

Comment: 早速修正し、関連付けを行いましたが、画面に変化がありませんでした。
PaymentDetailsItemにName,Quantity,Amountは設定されています。
さらに原因がわかりますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

PaymentDetailsItemをarrayで指定する際には、以下の設定が必要になります。

```
$caller =& PayPal::getCallerServices($profile);
$caller->USE_ARRAYKEY_AS_TAGNAME = true;
$caller->SUPRESS_OUTTAG_FOR_ARRAY = true;
$caller->OUTTAG_SUPRESS_ELEMENTS = array('PaymentDetailsItem');
```

あと、`SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails`の`orderTotal`ではなく、`PaymentDetails`の`orderTotal`の方を使っていただくことになります。

Comment: 無事、商品名、金額等が表示されるようになりました。